# How to check traffic download file by php

Tags: php

i need check user use download traffic per day write code php, and check download file by function readfile() or any ?

```
function getTraffic($curl, $data) 
{
    $length = mb_strlen($data, '8bit');
    $traffic += $length;
    $write = fopen('traffic.txt', 'ab');
    fwrite($write, $traffic);
    fclose($write);
}

$file = "D:\aa.rar";
$curl = curl_init($file);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'getTraffic');
echo curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: It seems like a pretty complicated way what you're trying to do as there is a function in PHP that obtains the number of bytes of a file: http://php.net/filesize - No need for a curl write function especially as you even use `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` and `echo`. Most likely you're stabbing in the dark here? What is your *concrete* programming question? Not that you run into the [X/Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem#) here

Comment: See also: https://dave.autonoma.ca/blog/2023/11/12/php-download-hit-counter/

Answer (score 0):

**example #1 :** [php-mysql-download-counter](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/02/php-mysql-download-counter/)

**example #2 :**

> Some very simple PHP would be the best option here.

```
<?php
$Down=$_GET['Down'];
?>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=<?php echo $Down; ?>">
</head>
<body>

<?php

$fp = fopen("Count.txt", "r");
$count = fread($fp, 1024);
fclose($fp);
$count = $count + 1;

//Un-comment to display the downloads.
echo "Downloads:" . $count . "";

$fp = fopen("Count.txt", "w");
fwrite($fp, $count);
fclose($fp);

?>

</body>
    </html>
```

> **or**

```
<?php
 $Down=$_GET['Down'];
?>

<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=<?php echo $Down; ?>">
 </head>
 <body>

 <?php

  $filePath = 'count.txt';

  // If file exists, read current count from it, otherwise, initialize it to 0
  $count = file_exists($filePath) ? file_get_contents($filePath) : 0;

  // Increment the count and overwrite the file, writing the new value
  file_put_contents($filePath, ++$count);

  // Display current download count
  echo "Downloads:" . $count;
 ?> 

 </body>
</html>
```

Call it download.php and then put a link to 'download.php?Down=download.zip'
Simple enough, and the number of donwloads will be stored in a text file.

> This post has been check by evergreen

Comment: hello this code counter download file ?, is not check download traffic ?

Comment: OK, insert another answer again to using this method for your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try some tool like New Relic. check url https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/php/new-relic-for-php

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about how curl has implemented the save-to-filestream function. I realized that it has to be something like a special CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, because stopping the script while saving to filestream leaves a file on my webspace which contains the already loaded part.

Therefor I tried it with CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION and it seems to be not as resource intensive as I thought.

Now I use register_shutdown_function to call a function which saves the used traffic. My CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION counts the loaded data = traffic.

It's also important that you store the current working directory in a variable if you want to save the traffic in a file. Because every relative path called in a registered shutdown function isn't relative to your root-directory, it's relative to the server root directory! You can also use absolut paths instead of cwd.

```
function readResponse($ch, $data) {
    global $traffic;

    $length = mb_strlen($data, '8bit');

    //count traffic
    $traffic += $length;
    //output loaded data
    echo $data;

    return $length;
}

function saveTraffic($username, $cwd) {
    global $traffic;

    $h = fopen($cwd.'/relative-path/traffic_'.$username.'.txt', 'ab');
    fwrite($h, $traffic);
    fclose($h);
}

//...

$cwd = getcwd();
register_shutdown_function('saveTraffic', $username, $cwd);

$traffic = 0;

//...
//Output download header information to client
//...

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'readResponse');

//...

curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: hello i try code but not work, i not sure how to use it .. thank you